# Query for a relation between Calendar Object and Esper's EQL

Tags: java, esper

There is a class becoming event objects.
class StockTickEvent
{
Calendar timestamp;
...
}

Also, there is an EQL statement.
select * from StockTickEvent.win:ext_timed(timestamp, 10 seconds)

Is the class right or valid for this EQL statement?
If so, what type can timestamp be? 
For example, the type of timestamp can be Calendar, Date, or long(unix time value).

Answer (score 0):

The ext-timed data window takes an expression returning a long value. You could add a method to the event returning the long-msec for the calendar.